# Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Unit\SomeTest::assertStatus()

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I wrote the test:

```
$response = $this->get('/something');
$response->assertStatus(200);
```

It displays this error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Unit\SomeTest::assertStatus()
```

I found how I can fix my problem (code is below) but I want to use first method:

```
  $response = $this->get('/something');

  $this->assertEquals(200, $this->response->status());
```

Why doesn't the first code work?

Comment: Is your `ExampleTest::class` extending the base `TestCase::class`?

Comment: Yes. It look like this `class ExampleTest extends TestCase`

Comment: Okay, are you using Laravel or Lumen, the microframework based on Laravel? And what version of Laravel are you using if the former?

Comment: I use Laravel 5.8

Comment: There is multiple classes named TestCase which one is it?

Answer (score 18):

I solved it by changing `use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` to `use Tests\TestCase`.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using the `TestCase` class `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` you should use `Tests\TestCase`. The following snippet should work.

```
use Tests\TestCase;

class ControllerTest extends TestCase
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this following code:

```
namespace Tests\Unit;
use Tests\TestCase;

class SampleTest extends TestCase{

  //your code

}
```